# Technical name for switch statement without breaks

Tags: switch-statement, break

Does anyone know the "technical name" for a switch statement without breaks?

I have looked through several textbooks and searched online for quite a while with no results.

Answer (score 2):

A switch statement with no breaks (and no loop, so it's not Duff's Device), I would just call a **jump table**.

Not one of the tools commonly used for structured programming, that's for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the help, jump/branch table is the term I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Fall through?

Or are you talking about a specific switch statement with no breaks, called [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)?

```
send(to, from, count)
register short *to, *from;
register count;
{
    register n=(count+7)/8;
    switch(count%8){
        case 0: do{ *to = *from++;
        case 7:     *to = *from++;
        case 6:     *to = *from++;
        case 5:     *to = *from++;
        case 4:     *to = *from++;
        case 3:     *to = *from++;
        case 2:     *to = *from++;
        case 1:     *to = *from++;
        }while(--n>0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When execution continues from one Case clause to the next it's called "fall-through".

```
switch (i) {
    case 1:
        // do something

    case 2:
        // do something else
        break;

    case 3:
        // do another thing
}
```

Execution will "fall through" from case 1 to case, but not from case 2 to case 3.  Is this what you're asking?